# Getting Maven to resolve missing dependencies with closest available matches

Tags: maven, dependency-management

When I look at my local Maven cache (`~/.m2/repository/`) I see 10-20 versions of certain artifacts, some of which are being used for only a single specific build (project). I would like to get rid of this duplication (true, they are different versions, but I'd still think a depending project would be able to tolerate a micro or minor version difference) and to somehow ask Maven to resort to the closest available version during dependency resolution, if a specific artifact version is missing in the local repository.

For example, if I have versions `1.0.0`, `1.1.2`, `1.4.0` and `2.0.0` of a `foo:bar` artifact in my local cache, I would like Maven to:

- use `1.1.2` for a build requiring `1.1.0`
- use `1.4.0` for a build requiring `1.4.10`
- use `2.0.0` for a build requiring `2.5.0`

without having to manually change the `pom` of the specific build(s).

I am fairly aware of the risks associated with switching dependency versions without proper analysis, and I'm only asking for a mechanism to be utilized for non-critical builds (such as a tool/library that I just cloned off a VCS, and would like to run and try out), preferably activated only when a particular flag is provided.

Is there something out there, like a Maven extension or plugin (that can be applied on a system-wide scale, and activated on demand with a flag), that can help me achieve my goal?

P.S.: Since the definition of "closest" could be ambiguous (given the fact that Maven may not know which of `1.4.0` and `2.0.0` is closer to `1.5.0` depending on the actual release versions lying between them), it would even be sufficient if I can specify the version on the build command (e.g. `mvn package -Dfoo:bar=1.4.0`), still without making any manual `pom` changes. (While this may already be possible for versions that have been specified as `<properties>` entries, I would like a generic solution where even hard-coded versions in transitive dependencies could be overridden.)

P.P.S.: Please note tht the project(s) that would be built would not have been authored/composed by me, so I don't really have control/authority over their actual `pom` files. What I'm looking for is a way to override dependency versions in their `pom` files without doing any manual modifications at source level.

Comment: Versions in maven can be ranges. Have you read [the POM reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html), section "Dependency Version Requirement Specification"?

Comment: @PaulHicks thanks, but I'm referring to building of arbitrary libraries (such as something that I just cloned off a VCS) whose `pom`s are not composed by me (and I would rather avoid changing them by hand before the build). Btw sorry if the word "(pet) projects" is misleading, I will remove it :)

Comment: This is what dependencyManagement is for. Your pom defines what versions / version ranges you accept. If a 3rd party pom depends on a 4th(?) party pom (say version 1.2) you can exclude that project's transient dependency in your parent pom, and include the correct version or version range yourself. I do it all the time for projects that hard code a dependency on JUnit 4.12, when I'm using 5.0.0-RC2...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm referring to *entirely third party* projects, over whose `pom`(s) I have no control; in other words, it is not "my pom" but the `pom` of a project that I obtained from some other source (and would prefer not to modify). I simply want to build a third-party project as-is (with no manual modifications), but force Maven to use a different set of dependency versions (by a system-level configuration/command-line parameter).

Comment: In _your_ pom in your project, that declares the dependencies on the 3rd party poms, you can [exclude their transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Exclusions), and you can include dependencies on the same jars with whatever versions and ranges you like. Apologies for not making this clearer: all the suggestions have been for you to change what your dependencies depend on. I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Updated answer with an example.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you have understood the situation correctly yet; there is no *my pom* in this scenario, I'm simply trying to build an entirely foreign/external project that I obtained from another source.

Comment: If you have no.pom, then how is your .m2/repository being used?

Comment: OK, let's say I have cloned some `github.com/foo/bar` (Maven) project and want to build it. But I don't locally have the exact versions of the dependencies that are declared in its `pom.xml`. Rather than changing the `pom.xml` manually, what I want to do is to tell Maven to automatically figure out the closest maching versions from my existing cache (`.m2/repository`) at build time.

Comment: Nothing. You cannot do that. You must edit the pom, that's how you control maven. You can delete all the versions you don't want from your local repo cache and turn off internet access and that will tell you what versions you need need to change in the pom and what dependencies you need to modify. But you have to modify dependencies in the pom, that's the only place they're controlled.

Comment: Hmm... I was hoping there would have been some hack / extension point on Maven itself that I could leverage to achieve the version override. I'll keep looking; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In order to change a transitive dependency, you need to exclude the transitive dependency in your direct dependency, then add a direct dependency in your pom.

For example, if you have a dependency on foo.jar (which depends on xyz.jar version 1.3) and on bar.jar (which depends on xyz.jar version 1.4), you can have these two sections in your pom:

```
<!-- Define the version(s) that you allow your dependencies to depend on. -->
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>projectXyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>[1.0,2.0)</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>projectFoo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>projectXyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>projectBar</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>5</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>projectXyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
...
<!-- Declare your dependencies but don't allow them to suck in their transitive dependencies. -->
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>projectXyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>projectFoo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>projectBar</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

This will pick up the most recent version of xyz.jar that it can, and that will be the only version used. When foo and bar use xyz, they'll have the version that you've allowed into your project.

The best thing to do is to use a [parent pom](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) (or bom: bill of materials) with a well-defined and well-maintained [dependencyManagement](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Management) section. Stick with a single version of everything, just share that "everything" between all projects. You can override versions in projects if you need to.

If you'd rather define versions in each project, then [version ranges](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Version_Requirement_Specification) will work. For the three examples you gave, you would use things like:

- [1.1.0, 1.2)
- [1.4.0, 1.5)
- [2.0.0,)

*(Open to correction here.. I haven't used version ranges in almost 10 years.)*

Finally, to get it to use versions that are already available, rather than download the best ones, all you can do is to use a [local artifact repository](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repository) as your central maven repository, and [turn off access to maven central and bintray](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories).

Comment: I doubt if the local repository option resolve the "version switching" requirement (`1.1.0` -> `1.1.2` etc), since Maven will still look for `1.1.0` in the local repository (if I understand correctly) and fail if it can't find it, rather than "deciding" to try other available versions?

Comment: Yes you have to keep your version ranges up to date, which is why I recommend the parent pom / bom solution (since then you have to update only one file to fix all projects). If your dependency/dependencyManagement range is [1.1.0,1.2) then maven will select 1.1.2 in preference to 1.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Closest thing I found so far: https://github.com/jboss/maven-dependency-management-extension/blob/master/README.md

It can be dropped into `${MAVEN_HOME}/lib/ext` and utilized for overriding versions of specific dependencies, e.g. `mvn install -Dversion:junit:junit=4.10`. While it doesn't offer the suggested "intelligent version derivation" approach, it's a good-enough solution.

Comment: Or maybe you could manually copy files around within ones `~/.m2/repository` folders...though copying sounds a bit scary... :)